# android gps location dont change coordinate

Tags: android, gps

My application with alertdialog call gps position and store data in edittext .
When push button ok the coordinates are stored in listview .

```
public void addCoor(View view) {
    // creating the EditText widget programatically
    final EditText editTextLat = new EditText(com.example.bo.datatest.InsertRilev.this);
    final EditText editTextLong = new EditText(com.example.bo.datatest.InsertRilev.this);
    String posizione = "";
    double latitude = 0;
    double longitude = 0;
    gps = new GPSTracker(com.example.bo.datatest.InsertRilev.this);

    // check if GPS enabled
    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

        latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        longitude = gps.getLongitude();

        // \n is for new line
        // posizione= "nLat: " + latitude + "Long: " + longitude;
    } else {
        // can't get location
        // GPS or Network is not enabled
        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }
    editTextLat.setText(Double.toString(latitude));
    editTextLong.setText(Double.toString(longitude));
    // create the AlertDialog as final
    //Context context = com.example.bo.datatest.InsertRilev.getContext();
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(com.example.bo.datatest.InsertRilev.this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(com.example.bo.datatest.InsertRilev.this)
            .setTitle("Rilevamento delle posizione attuale ")
            .setMessage("Coordinate attuali: ")

                    // Set the action buttons
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // Coordinate coo = new Coordinate(Float.valueOf(editTextLat.getText().toString()),Float.valueOf(editTextLong.getText().toString()),  ril_id);
                    // coo_id = db.addCoordinate(coo);
                    //dati =new String[] {editTextLat.getText().toString() +"," + editTextLong.getText().toString()};
                    arrayList.add(editTextLat.getText().toString() + "," + editTextLong.getText().toString());
                    // next thing you have to do is check if your adapter has changed
                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(com.example.bo.datatest.InsertRilev.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
                    ((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();

                    cooview.setAdapter(adapter);

                }


            })

            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // removes the AlertDialog in the screen
                }
            })
            .create();
    layout.addView(editTextLat);

    layout.addView(editTextLong);


    dialog.setView(layout);
    dialog.show();
    //chiudo il dialog e richiamo la funzione per scrivere la posizione rilevata
    dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            enableButton();
        }
    });

}
```

For return gps coordinate i use the class gpsTracker

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        /*isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);*/
        isNetworkEnabled = false;

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

The first time i call the dialog the coordinate are right , but  after i change physical position and i reopen the dialog  the coordinate are the same of first time like are cached.

Comment: *Someone have a idea ?* stop using **useless and extremely bad androidhive's tutorial**

Answer (score 1):

Minimize the  MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES 1 min to 0

Answer (score 0):

Try putting Logs in your onLocationChanged() function as it is the one fired on location changes. The Location object passed as parameter in this function has all your new location values.